# How do I return a 404 status where invalid parameters are passed to my ASP.NET MVC controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to return a HTTP status `404` if invalid arguments are passed to my controller. For example if I have a controller that looks like:

```
public ActionResult GetAccount(int id)
{
   ...
}
```

Then I want to return a `404` if say urls such as these are encountered:

```
/GetAccount
/GetAccount/notanumber
```

i.e. I want to trap the `ArgumentException` that is thrown.

I know I could use a nullable type:

```
public ActionResult GetAccount(int? id)
{
  if(id == null) throw new HttpException(404, "Not found");
}
```

But that's pretty icky and repetitious.

I was hoping I could add this to my controllers where necessary:

```
[HandleError(View="Error404", ExceptionType = typeof(ArgumentException))]
public class AccountsController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult GetAccount(int id)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

But that doesn't appear to work well.

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404-in-asp-net-mvc/2577095#2577095) which nearly solves my problem:

In that answer an abstract *BaseController* is created from which you derive all your other controllers from:

```
public abstract class MyController : Controller
{
    #region Http404 handling

    protected override void HandleUnknownAction(string actionName)
    {
        // If controller is ErrorController dont 'nest' exceptions
        if (this.GetType() != typeof(ErrorController))
            this.InvokeHttp404(HttpContext);
    }

    public ActionResult InvokeHttp404(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        IController errorController = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ErrorController>();
        var errorRoute = new RouteData();
        errorRoute.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
        errorRoute.Values.Add("action", "Http404");
        errorRoute.Values.Add("url", httpContext.Request.Url.OriginalString);
        errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(
             httpContext, errorRoute));

        return new EmptyResult();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This works great at handling unknown actions with a `404` but doesn't allow me to handle invalid data as a `404`.

Can I safely override [`Controller.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onexception.aspx) like this:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
  if(filterContext.Exception.GetType() == typeof(ArgumentException))
  {
    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    this.InvokeHttp404(filterContext.HttpContext);
  }
  else
  {
    base.OnException(filterContext);
  }
}
```

On the surface it seems to work, but am I storing up any problems by doing this?

Is this semantically correct thing to do?

Answer (score 6):

### Best way? Action method selector attribute!

To actually avoid nullable method arguments I suggest that you write an [Action Method Selector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionmethodselectorattribute.aspx) attribute that will actually only match your action method when `id` is supplied. It won't say that argument wasn't supplied but that it couldn't match any action methods for the given request.

I would call this action selector `RequireRouteValuesAttribute` and would work this way:

```
[RequireRouteValues("id")]
public ActionResult GetAccount(int id)
{
    ...
}
```

### Why is this the best solution for your problem?

If you look at your code you'd like to return a 404 on actions that match name but parameter binding failed (either because it wasn't supplied or any other reason). Your action so to speak **requires** particular action parameter otherwise a 404 is returned.

So when adding action selector attribute adds the requirement on the action so it has to match name (this is given by MVC) and also require particular action parameters. Whenever `id` is not supplied this action is not matched. If there's another action that does match is not the issue here because that particular action will get executed. The main thing is accomplished. Action doesn't match for invalid route request and a 404 is returned instead.

### There's <strike>an app</strike> code for that!

Check [my blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/improving-aspnet-mvc-maintainability.html) that implements this kind of attribute that you can use out of the box. It does exactly what you're after: it won't match your action method if route data provided doesn't have all required values.

Comment: thanks @jgauffin... MVC actually has many customization hooks that we're not even aware of... I know I don't know about many... ;)

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: this does not cover all the cases*

For urls in your examples, returning 404 can be done in single line. Just add route constraint for `id` parameter.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }, // Parameter defaults
    new { id = @"\d+" } // restrict id to be required and numeric
);
```

And that's all. Now any matching url that has no `id` or `id` is not numeric, autimatically triggers not found error (for which there are plenty of ways to handle, one in your example, another by using custom `HandleErrorAttribute`, etc). And you can use non-nullable `int` parameters on your actions.

Comment: But... He probably doesn't require all controllers and actions to supply IDs... This is just partial solution for some edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by adding this route at the end of all routes:

```
routes.MapRoute("CatchAllErrors", "{*url}",
    new { controller = "Error", action = "NotFound" }
);
```

Note: First I followed this: [How can I properly handle 404 in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7499406/114029)